# new_style_message is not working anymore for me, any other workaround to send apprequest with custom message as branchout/glassdoor does?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

For sending the apprequest with custom message, I was using a js api, undocumented parameter `new_style_message` set to be true, but now it seems to stop working.

This is how I was sending the request:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
       message: 'notification message',
       title: 'tile of request',
       data: '$gid',
       to: user_ids,
       new_style_message:true
      }, requestCallback);
```

Does anybody have any workarounds?  Please help.

**Update**: The request is being sent properly, it's just not showing up with the custom message to whom I sent the request. I want to know is there a way I can send it with a custom message?

Comment: you taught us a lesson: never use undocumented parameters

Comment: how about removing the `new_style_message` ? does it work ?

Comment: see the edit, it works even with `new_style_message` but custom message that i want to send is not going. notification goes as ***** has sent you a request.

Comment: try FB OpenGraph . You can set the message structure .

Comment: _“notification goes as ***** has sent you a request.”_ – that’s how invites are __supposed to work__.

Comment: yes, but how branchout send the request with their custom message "abcd has invited you to join his profession network"? I want to know is there a way i can send custom message in notification

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Sending apprequests from the Graph API isn't possible.

Comment: Graph API & OpenGraph protocol are not the same thing.

Comment: @shivan: yeah i know opengraph, I have used it but don't know how to send apprequest using the same? can you please point me to some reference.