# Change Facebook Notification message

Tags: javascript, facebook

So i am sending facebook notifications with the javascript API using the following:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: message,
    to: ids
}, requestCallback);
alert('Notification Sent!');
```

Works fine, its just when you get the notification & click the notification in the top left does not out put your message just says:

> "**NAME** sent you a request"

So I would like to know how if possible to put the message in the notification bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `new_style_message` parameter, notification should go with your message. then your block for sending notification will be like:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: message,
    to: ids,
    new_style_message: true
}, requestCallback);
alert('Notification Sent!');
```

hope it works, actually its an undocumented parameter, so I would say don't rely on it completely. btw I use it anyway.

Comment: I would say that it is unwise to rely upon undocumented parameters, especially where Facebook Platform is concerned!

Comment: yeah, I know.. that I have mentioned in answer as well. But I think if it is not causing any problem anyway so why not use it. until it works, apprequest notification will be sent with message, if it stop working anyhow notification will be sent as `sender has sent you a request`.

Comment: The problem is that there are no requirements for non-documented features to remain working, as you have encountered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891255/new-style-message-is-not-working-anymore-for-me-any-other-workaround-to-send-ap

Comment: yeah, actually sometimes it sends notification with message and sometimes it sends as `sender has sent you a request`. that's why I had asked that question for any other alternative but didn't get one :-(

Answer (score 3):

Are you testing using an App that runs on Facebook.com (such as a Canvas App or Page App)? If so, you should instead use the Notifications API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/

This is the newer version and allows you to customise the text of the actual notification. The `message` parameter in the `apprequests` dialog is just customizing a separate bit of text that appears on the App Center [requests page](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests). It was never intended for actually customizing the Notification text itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: As a follow up to my answer, I've just noticed you are sending a User to User request (the Notifications API is for App to User requests). The notification text for User to User requests is not currently customizable.